# Google cloud storage uploads 0 Bytes Node.js for all files

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

Upload to google cloud storage using node.js doesn't have error but uploads zero bytes
I am using Google-Cloud-Storage. This code will save an object in the bucket but it is just empty. It shows a size of 0 Bytes

```
const gc = new Storage({
    keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, "../faslearn-ba6c817cfcea.json"),
    projectId: "faslearn"
});
//const gc = new Storage()

//gc.getBuckets().then(x => console.log(x))
const bucket = gc.bucket('faslearn_files')

const upload = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.file) {
            res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
            return;
        }

        //Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
        const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({ resumable: false, gzip: true });

        blobStream.on('error', err => {
            next(err);
        });

        blobStream.on('finish', () => {
            // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
            const publicUrl = format(
                `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
            );
            res.status(200).send(publicUrl);
        });

        blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);

     
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(" some where");
        res.status(500).send({
            message: `Could not upload the file: ${req.file.originalname}. ${err}`,
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason to upload it as a stream? The SDK has a `upload()` method.

Comment: can you please give me an example of how to do it that way? @Dharmaraj